# Python: Scrapy CSV exports incorrectly?

Tags: python, csv, export, scrapy

I am simply trying to write to a csv. However I have two separate for-statements, therefore the data from each for-statement exports independently and breaks order. Suggestions?

```
def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        titles = hxs.select('//td[@class="title"]')
        subtext = hxs.select('//td[@class="subtext"]')
        items = []
        for title in titles:
            item = HackernewsItem()
            item["title"] = title.select("a/text()").extract()
            item["url"] = title.select("a/@href").extract()
            items.append(item)
        for score in subtext:
            item = HackernewsItem()
            item["score"] = score.select("span/text()").extract()
            items.append(item)
        return items
```

As is apparent in the image below, the second for-statement prints below the others instead of "among" others as header does.

CSV image attached:[image: csv file]

and github link for full file: https://github.com/nchlswtsn/scrapy/blob/master/items.csv

Comment: can you upload the CSV file?

Comment: @boussouira Yup! Updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your order of exporting element is logical to what you find in CSV file, first you exported all the titles then all subtext elements.
I guess you are trying to scrap HN articles, here is my suggestion:

```
def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    titles = hxs.select('//td[@class="title"]')
    items = []
    for title in titles:
        item = HackernewsItem()
        item["title"] = title.select("a/text()").extract()
        item["url"] = title.select("a/@href").extract()
        item["score"] = title.select('../td[@class="subtext"]/span/text()').extract()
        items.append(item)
    return items
```

I didn't test it, but it will give you an idea.

Answer (score 1):

The CSV module from Python 2.7 does not support Unicode, so it's suggested to use [unicodecsv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/unicodecsv) instead.

```
$pip install unicodecsv
```

> The unicodecsv is a drop-in replacement for Python 2's csv module which supports unicode strings without a hassle.

And then use this instead of `import csv`

```
import unicodecsv as csv
```

Comment: I typically export to CSV via arguments at launch (scrapy crawl myspider -o items.csv). Can I accommodate that with unicodecsv somehow?

Comment: You'd have to check which CSV module scrapy is using. [Seems they are using regular csv module.](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=csv) Going to python 3 and this issue goes away.

Comment: @Charles Watson Did you figure out how to use unicodecsv at launch? I'm having the same issue as you.