# How do I stop Scrapy 0.24 from returning funky characters when exporting to csv?

Tags: python, csv, scrapy

A page I'm scraping for data with Scrapy 0.24 (with Pythong 2.7.9, on Windows 7 64-bit) is returning `â€“` instead of the en dash's numeric entity code `&#8211;` that you can see when you view the pages source. That's just an example of course, this happens to all special characters that exist on the page. The page I'm scraping has `<meta charset="utf-8">` declared in the `<head>`.

What do I need to do in my Scrapy code in order to successfully write the correct characters to a .csv file?

After some new research I [discovered this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29808222/556079) to another question. Apparently the csv module in Python 2.7 does not support Unicode. Although I am at a loss as to how to use this information to solve my problem.

Here is my spider code.

**products.py**

```
import scrapy
import urlparse

from allenheath.items import ProductItem
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse

class productsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "products"
    allowed_domains = ["http://www.allen-heath.com/"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.allen-heath.com/ahproducts/ilive-80/",
        "http://www.allen-heath.com/ahproducts/ilive-112/"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('/html'):
            item = ProductItem()
            item['model'] = sel.css('#prodsingleouter > div > div > h2::text').extract() # The value I'd like to use to name my images.
            item['shortdesc'] = sel.css('#prodsingleouter > div > div > h3::text').extract()
            item['desc'] = sel.css('#tab1 #productcontent').extract()
            item['series'] = sel.css('#pagestrip > div > div > a:nth-child(3)::text').extract()
            item['imageorig'] = sel.css('#prodsingleouter > div > div > h2::text').extract()
            item['image_urls'] = sel.css('#tab1 #productcontent .col-sm-9 img').xpath('./@src').extract()
            item['image_urls'] = [urlparse.urljoin(response.url, url) for url in item['image_urls']]
            yield item
```

I run the spider using the following from the Command Prompt:

`scrapy crawl products -o items.csv`

Comment: have you tried specifying the encoding of the string data you are writing to the file using `sometextdata.encode('utf-8')`?

Comment: I've tried specifying utf-8 like so: `item['desc'] = sel.css('#tab1 #productcontent').extract().encode('utf-8')` but that was no help. In what other way could I try that?

Comment: I don't quite understand what method you are using to save the data to a file. If you `print item['desc']` to stdout do you see the same characters as in the csv or are they being written differently? You may have to use the utf-8 when you take the data out of the item rather than when you put it in.

Comment: When I use `print item['desc']` I get unicode in the command prompt instead of the junk like `â€“` that appears in my csv when I use `scrapy crawl products -o items.csv`. It's not the UTF-8 that I really want, but it's better.

Comment: @jimmykup I can't reproduce the problem. I've ran a local version of your spider, changed the `desc` extraction to only `sel.extract()` and I get the nice Unicode characters in the CSV. That junk you're getting looks like Unicode interpreted as ISO-8859-1 -- maybe you can try force-loading the body as unicode: `sel = scrapy.Selector(text=response.body_as_unicode())` ?

Comment: @elias I tried using just `item['desc'] = sel.extract()` like you suggested. In my .csv I'm still getting garbage unfortunately. Are you on Windows? Maybe it's an OS thing? I tried adding `sel = scrapy.Selector(text=response.body_as_unicode())` after `for sel in response.xpath('/html'):` and it had no effect.

Comment: @elias @Karl Something to note, I just tried this, if I export to JSON with `scrapy crawl products -o items.json` I get Unicode instead of junk characters. If I open the .csv file in a text editor, there no junk characters and no unicode characters. Everything is as it appears on the website it's pulled from. So it looks like scrapy isn't converting to unicode when it saves to csv. Again I'm on Windows if that means anything for the .csv issue.

Comment: @jimmykup no, I'm on Linux. agree, looks like an environment thing.